# Git push heroku master error : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-random==1.2.1

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, intel-mkl

While trying to `git push heroku master` I am encountering an error :

A snippet of the error:

```
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-service==2.3.0 (from -r /tmp/build_3a708448/requirements.txt (line 37)) (from versions: 2.4.0)
        remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl-service==2.3.0 (from -r /tmp/build_3a708448/requirements.txt (line 37))
        remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
        remote:
        remote:  !     Push failed
```

The Full details from `cmd` prompt

```
(debasis_venv) C:\Users\LENOVO\12042021\Sec20_Build_A_Website>heroku login
    heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
    Opening browser to https://cli-auth.heroku.com/auth/cli/browser/d611f093-8415-4dbd-a30b-93e7861079d3?requestor=SFMyNTY.g2gDbQAAAA0xMjIuMTYzLjU0Ljc3bgYAYcP3vHkBYgABUYA.qwoIt7JBUdCHNCOZADmhuocvQPTnXlxq7UvuoM9jaDY
    Logging in... done
    Logged in as debasissil@yahoo.com
    
    (debasis_venv) C:\Users\LENOVO\12042021\Sec20_Build_A_Website>git init
    Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Users/LENOVO/12042021/Sec20_Build_A_Website/.git/
    
    (debasis_venv) C:\Users\LENOVO\12042021\Sec20_Build_A_Website>git add .
    
    (debasis_venv) C:\Users\LENOVO\12042021\Sec20_Build_A_Website>git config --global user.email "debasissil@yahoo.com"
    
    (debasis_venv) C:\Users\LENOVO\12042021\Sec20_Build_A_Website>git config --global user.name "debasissilpython"
    
    (debasis_venv) C:\Users\LENOVO\12042021\Sec20_Build_A_Website>git commit -m "first commit"
    [master ac903ae] first commit
     1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
    
    (debasis_venv) C:\Users\LENOVO\12042021\Sec20_Build_A_Website>heroku git:remote --app debasissil
    set git remote heroku to https://git.heroku.com/debasissil.git
    
    (debasis_venv) C:\Users\LENOVO\12042021\Sec20_Build_A_Website>git push heroku master
    Enumerating objects: 31, done.
    Counting objects: 100% (31/31), done.
    Delta compression using up to 2 threads
    Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (31/31), 103.51 KiB | 2.72 MiB/s, done.
    Total 31 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote:
    remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
    remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
    remote: -----> Python app detected
    remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
    remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.8.10
    remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
    remote: -----> Installing python-3.8.8
    remote: -----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
    remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
    remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
    remote:        Collecting addict==2.4.0
    remote:          Downloading addict-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.8 kB)
    remote:        Collecting aiofiles==0.6.0
    remote:          Downloading aiofiles-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
    remote:        Collecting backcall==0.2.0
    remote:          Downloading backcall-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
    remote:        Collecting branca==0.4.2
    remote:          Downloading branca-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
    remote:        Collecting certifi==2020.12.5
    remote:          Downloading certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
    remote:        Collecting chardet==4.0.0
    remote:          Downloading chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
    remote:        Collecting click==7.1.2
    remote:          Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
    remote:        Collecting colorama==0.4.4
    remote:          Downloading colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
    remote:        Collecting csv-to-geojson==0.0.1
    remote:          Downloading csv_to_geojson-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
    remote:        Collecting cycler==0.10.0
    remote:          Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
    remote:        Collecting decorator==5.0.6
    remote:          Downloading decorator-5.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (8.8 kB)
    remote:        Collecting demjson==2.2.4
    remote:          Downloading demjson-2.2.4.tar.gz (131 kB)
    remote:        Collecting et-xmlfile==1.1.0
    remote:          Downloading et_xmlfile-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
    remote:        Collecting Flask==2.0.1
    remote:          Downloading Flask-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
    remote:        Collecting folium==0.12.1
    remote:          Downloading folium-0.12.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
    remote:        Collecting geographiclib==1.50
    remote:          Downloading geographiclib-1.50-py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
    remote:        Collecting geojson==2.5.0
    remote:          Downloading geojson-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
    remote:        Collecting geopy==2.1.0
    remote:          Downloading geopy-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
    remote:        Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
    remote:          Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
    remote:        Collecting h11==0.12.0
    remote:          Downloading h11-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
    remote:        Collecting httpcore==0.13.3
    remote:          Downloading httpcore-0.13.3-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
    remote:        Collecting httpx==0.18.1
    remote:          Downloading httpx-0.18.1-py3-none-any.whl (75 kB)
    remote:        Collecting idna==2.10
    remote:          Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
    remote:        Collecting ipykernel==5.3.4
    remote:          Downloading ipykernel-5.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (120 kB)
    remote:        Collecting ipython==7.22.0
    remote:          Downloading ipython-7.22.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
    remote:        Collecting ipython-genutils==0.2.0
    remote:          Downloading ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
    remote:        Collecting itsdangerous==2.0.0
    remote:          Downloading itsdangerous-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
    remote:        Collecting jedi==0.17.0
    remote:          Downloading jedi-0.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
    remote:        Collecting Jinja2==3.0.1
    remote:          Downloading Jinja2-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
    remote:        Collecting jupyter-client==6.1.12
    remote:          Downloading jupyter_client-6.1.12-py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
    remote:        Collecting jupyter-core==4.7.1
    remote:          Downloading jupyter_core-4.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
    remote:        Collecting justpy==0.1.5
    remote:          Downloading justpy-0.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (4.4 MB)
    remote:        Collecting kiwisolver==1.3.1
    remote:          Downloading kiwisolver-1.3.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
    remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==2.0.1
    remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (30 kB)
    remote:        Collecting matplotlib==3.3.4
    remote:          Downloading matplotlib-3.3.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.6 MB)
    remote:        Collecting mkl-fft==1.3.0
    remote:          Downloading mkl_fft-1.3.0-1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (250 kB)
    remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-service==2.3.0 (from -r /tmp/build_3a708448/requirements.txt (line 37)) (from versions: 2.4.0)
    remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl-service==2.3.0 (from -r /tmp/build_3a708448/requirements.txt (line 37))
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !       Push rejected to debasissil.
    remote:
    To https://git.heroku.com/debasissil.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/debasissil.git'
    
    (debasis_venv) C:\Users\LENOVO\12042021\Sec20_Build_A_Website>
```

I tried reinstalling it but it says Requirement already satisfied. The issue is also with `mkl-random==1.2.1`

I am doing it from virtual env.

Please advice.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git. It's purely a heroku and/or pip-requirements issue (presumably related to intel-mkl since that's what the complaint is about).

Comment: This error is because pypi wheel for mkl_fft  is not updated for python 3.8. You could try installing this with  conda install as in @Athira 's answer. Or another option would be to downgrade python

Answer (score 1):

You could install mkl-service in a conda environment and execute your workload. Please follow the below steps:

Step 1 : Create conda environment

```
conda create -n <env_name> python=<version>
```

Step 2 : Activate conda environment

```
conda activate <env_name>
```

Step3 : Install mkl-service

```
conda install -c intel mkl-service==2.3.0
```